# Rails4 How can I tweet with a picture from a website with sferik / twitter gem?

Tags: ruby, twitter, ruby-on-rails-4

I know i can tweet with update method like `client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")`
but how can i tweet with a picture from a website? Can I use `update_with_media` method with `URL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update_with_media method expects an image file

```
# @param media [File, Hash] A File object with your picture (PNG, JPEG or GIF)
# ...
# ...
def update_with_media(status, media, options = {})
```

Source: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb#L224

To use an URL of a website for the media you should use another gem that captures a URL to an image (e.g. https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) and then send that image with the update_with_media method.